# Existence of a Riemann structure on every differentiable manifold

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Following is a exercise from Warner's Foundations of differentiable manifolds and a solution I found online.

[image]

[image]

I just don't get how it can be easily said that $<,>_{\alpha}$ is smooth on each chart. Can someone provide an outline of a proof or an explanation? Thank you!

Comment: In each chart, $<,>_\alpha$ is the the image under a smooth map of the ordinary inner product on Euclidean space.

Comment: @LeeMosher Can you further explain as to what you mean by image under the smooth of the ordinary inner product. I don't quite get that part.

Comment: For any point $m \in U_\alpha$ and any tangent vectors $M_m$, we have $<v,w>_{\alpha,m} = <D\psi_\alpha(v),D\psi_\alpha(w)>$, and so $<v,w>_{\alpha,m}$ is a smooth function of $m \in U_\alpha$, $v, w \in M_m$. And since the scalar functions $\phi_\alpha(m)$ are also smooth, and since scalar multiplication and summation are smooth operations, it follows that $<v,w>_m$ is a smooth function of $m \in M$, $v,w \in M_m$.